# Is there a way to ignore some images while using flow_from_directory in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a training set of many images, and want to use the function flow_from_directory but ignore a list of images which have bad labels. Is there a way to do it without deleting the image themselves from the folder?